# unix bash remove xml tag if value is X

Tags: bash, sed

i have an xml which looks like this:

```
<b>
    hTTp://test.com:7001
</b>
<b>
    hTTp://anothertest:7001
</b>
```

I'd like to remove the whole  tag if the value is test

i tried to do something like:

```
sed -i -e "/<b> /, ${SERVER_ADDRESS}/ <\/b>/d"
```

after running the command the xml should look like this:

```
<b>
hTTp://anothertest:7001
</b>
```

Comment: what value ? you mean if the url contains test in its name ? Or if the tag is <test> ? or something else ?

Comment: the value inside the b tag is test

Comment: That's two votes to close. Try again.

Comment: this is still quite unclear. I suggest you edit your question and provide an example of a valid tag and one of a tag that should be deleted. (as of now, I understand that you want to remove tags that are like this : `<b>test</b>`)

Comment: you're right....that's exactly what i want to do.

Comment: then add it to your question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24554675/edit) it

Comment: Your input is not valid XML, it is missing a root element that contains the two `<b>` elements.

Comment: i know...its a tag based config file....

Comment: Its still unclear why you want `hTTp://anothertest:7001` and not `hTTp://test.com:7001` both contain `test`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

```
$ cat in.txt
<root>
  <b>foo</b>
  <b>bar</b>
</root>
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//b[contains(text(), "foo")]' < in.txt
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <b>bar</b>
</root>
```

Comment: need to use sed or something like that...can't installxmlstartlet on that machine.

Comment: Regular expressions are not meant to parse XML. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/.

Comment: @tomerz Then use an XML parser in Python or Perl which are most likely installed.